# Relative image path in renewed \maketitle

Tags: graphics, titles, input, paths

To minimize the amount of copy-pasting I have to do between documents/projects, I've decided to create a separate file in which I renew the `\maketitle` command. This file (`title.tex`) should then be used as input for any project (in this case `main.tex`):

File `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{/path/to/title}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

File `title.tex`:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry,graphicx}
\geometry{a4paper}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \includegraphics{image}
}
```

This doesn't work because the path provided for `\includegraphics` is relative. Making the path absolute would solve the problem, but that wouldn't make the file as portable as I would like.

Is there any way I can keep using a relative path for my image?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61907/set-the-default-path-to-images-directory/62000#62000

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but using TEXINPUTS is not very portable.
What would work (for me) is to read the path to the `title.tex` file from within the file and use that in the path to `image`, but I have no idea how. There is probably a more elegant way to do something like what I want. How do packages provide images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was actually fairly simple: Turn `title.tex` into `title.sty` and place it in the `texmf` folder (together with the `image` file):

```
%% This package provides a modified title
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{title}[2012/08/13 v1 title]

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry,graphicx}
\geometry{a4paper}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \includegraphics{image}
}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `title.sty'.
```

And in use the package in `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{title}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

I have no idea if this is the proper way to do it, but it works well.

Comment: So what is difference with my yesterday answer? :-)

Comment: Your answer still required the path to `image`, which wasn't what I wanted - and apparently isn't necessary. Your answer did lead me to my own answer - so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
% Main.tex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mytitle}
\begin{document}
    \MakeTitle{/path/to/image}
\end{document}
```

```
% mytitle.sty

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01] 
\ProvidesPackage{mytitle}[2012/08/12 v0.01 LaTeX package to include title]  
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\MakeTitle}[1]{\includegraphics{#1}}

\endinput
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply create a command that write the path of the directory with things to be included (image.png and title.tex) and put inside `\input`:

```
%main.tex    
\documentclass{article}
    \newcommand{\onlypath}{/some/path/things}
    \input{\onlypath/title}
    \begin{document}
        \maketitle
    \end{document}
```

as well as in the `\includegraphics` command:

```
%title.tex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry,graphicx}
\geometry{a4paper}
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{
    \includegraphics{\onlypath/image}
}
```